# error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. when installing bundler for react native CLI

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I realized that because I was using expo go to create my react native project I was unable to link firebase to it, so I decided I would use the CLI in hopes that I could follow a tutorial online that I found that uses it. Long story short spent 4 hours fiddling with ruby, homebrew, watchman, node, etc. And I have nearly got it to download the React native CLI, however I am getting this error. I originally was getting an error that said the Gem needed 2.7.5 and I was using 3.0.0 so I switched it using rvm and now this is the error I get. TBH if someone knows how to connect firebase to react-native using expo go I would rather just keep working on that project than starting a new one, but I don't think it is possible, so if someone can help me figure out why I am getting this error that would be helpful as well.

here is the full error:

```
Installing dependencies
✔ CocoaPods (https://cocoapods.org/) is not installed. CocoaPods is necessary for the iOS project to run correctly. Do you want to install it? › Yes, with gem (may require sudo)
✔ Installing CocoaPods
✖ Installing Bundler
error Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev
stuff/personal/90dayz/Dayz90/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby -I
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20221226-91293-hikzkd.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -lffi... no
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi... no
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi-8... no
checking for whether -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL is accepted as LDFLAGS... no
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev
stuff/personal/90dayz/Dayz90/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev
stuff/personal/90dayz/Dayz90/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** ["/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev
stuff/personal/90dayz/Dayz90/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for
inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev
stuff/personal/90dayz/Dayz90/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-22/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out

/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:99:in
`run'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in
`block in make'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in
`each'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in
`make'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in
`block in build'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tempfile.rb:291:in
`open'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:30:in
`build'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:169:in
`block in build_extension'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in
`synchronize'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in
`build_extension'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in
`block in build_extensions'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in
`each'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:844:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in
`install'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in
`do_install'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in
`block in worker_pool'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`loop'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
/Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
      typhoeus was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
        ethon was resolved to 0.16.0, which depends on
          ffi

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
    at createFromTemplate (/Users/jonnywerthman/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:169:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/jonnywerthman/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:222:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/jonnywerthman/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:140:9)
```

I tried a lot of different stuff, but I am nearing my breaking point with this. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** ["/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev] Error 2
```

This means *"The string `"/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev` doesn't have an end set of quotation marks and I was expecting to find one."* And ultimately that means it can't continue executing.

I don't know and can't speak to why the path isn't being properly quoted. It's probably a misconfiguration of the tools that are being run.

The fastest and simplest solution is to remove the whitespace from the path, so that you turn this:

```
/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev stuff/
```

Into this:

```
/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Devstuff/
```

Then retry the operation.